# open new window without the browser giving warning that is a popup

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on mvc2 and i'm trying to open from javascript in a new window something.
if i only use inside the js function window.open("action/action/"+param) like this

```
function(){ 
 window.open("action/action/"+param);
}
```

it works perfectly and the browser does not warn me that it is a new popup that i'm opening.
But if i make an ajax call before the window.open, the browser tells me that is a new popup and if i accept it.

```
if (json.data && json.data.URL)
{
      window.open("action/action/"+param);//opens in a new window only if i accept popups 
}
```

how can i make it work without the browser considering it as popup?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810641/prevent-window-popup-warning-in-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't popup a window "randomly" it needs to be right after the user has clicked something or did an action so that the browser doesn't think it's a random ad popup.

Answer (score 0):

The window has to open as a direct result of the user's input. For example, you could open a new window inside a click handler. It's not full proof by any means, but it's one measure the browser can take to try and prevent unwanted popups.